# aws s3 bucket delete issue

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am deleting bucket from AWS S3 and versioning is enabled, but it's showing this error:

> aws_s3_bucket.bucket: Error deleting S3 Bucket: BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions of the bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket        = "${module.naming.aws_s3_bucket}"
  acl           = "log-delivery-write"
  force_destroy = true

versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

I am using Terraform version 10.8

Comment: and do you disagree with it that the bucket is not empty, or that other versions exist?

Comment: I do not disagree. I know bucket have data and multiple versions are there. But, force_destory would not work in this case?

Comment: Did you have `force_destroy = true` on the last apply or have you added it before running the destroy? I have seen issues with trying to set `force_destroy` as part of the destroy and it failing but it being fine if that was applied and then a destroy is ran.

Comment: update your terraform to `v0.11.5`, delete all initiate terraform files like `.terraform` and `*.tfstate` file, and start from the beginning(init, plan, apply)

Comment: I am posting late the problem was solved. The problem was solved through include lifecycle create_before_destroy.

Answer (score 2):

`force_destroy` is not applying because it only can affect the `aws s3` bucket directly. Not inherit with it's containing childs.

If you want to delete all objects you need to run:

```
aws s3 rm s3://name-of-bucket --recursive
```

To get rid of all versions within the object that are still existing you better run:

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket name-of-bucket --delete '{"Objects": [{"Key": "*", "VersionId": "*"}]}'
```

To be fair to others who tried to answer your question it is indeed the obvious answer, no, force_destroy can't manage that. But I hope my explanation can give you an inside why it is the case. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
"force_destroy": true,
"versioning": [
              {
                "enabled": true,
                "mfa_delete": false
              }
```

is working as expected

I have Terraform v0.13.4